# Number of elements of each order in Sn

Tags: abstract-algebra

The elements in $$S_{n}$$ have the following orders: 1,2,3,...,n
I'm thinking about a specific case of $$S_{7}$$
Now, to find how many elements of order 6, for example, I look at the following permutations: $$\alpha = (a b c d e f),$$ $$\beta = (a b)(c d e),$$ $$\gamma = (a b)(c d e)(f)$$

For $\alpha$, there are 5! elements, for $\beta$, there are $\frac{5*6}{2}*\frac{3*4*2}{3} = 120 $ etc. My question is, do I have to count $\gamma$ ? Because if I proceed in the same way, I get more elements than 7!

Comment: The elements of $S_n$ can have order greater than $n$, e.g., $(12)(345)$ in $S_5$ has order 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write an element of $S_7$ like
$$
(abcdef)
$$
in cycle notation, you're using fewer than $7$ symbols, so there's one element which you aren't explicitly saying how you're permuting. (For example, if your cycle is $(124567)$, you aren't saying what happens to $3$.)

Part of the convention of cycle notation that each symbol you don't write is mapped to itself: that is,
$$
(abcdef)=(abcdef)(g)
$$

So you don't need to worry about cycle types with $1$-cycles in them: they've already been taken care of. That is, your $\beta$- and $\gamma$-type cycles are identical to each other. (Or, equivalently, you could worry about cycle types with $1$-cycles in them, but then you should always be using seven symbols to describe them; e.g., you could ask about cycle types
$$
\alpha=(abcdef)(g)\\
\beta=(abc)(de)(f)(g)
$$
and so on.)